# Nextjs API timeout when sending email through SMTP

Tags: reactjs, next.js, smtp, nodemailer, vercel

We have a cPanel email and I am trying to send emails to the customers of our website with nodemailer. I'm using Nextjs and Vercel for deployment. I created an api route that handles this. Locally everything works fine but in deployment, the request takes more than 10 seconds to execute and the api times out. Is there a possible workaround?

First I tried sending the email from inside getServerSideProps, but soon realized that this was a very bad idea. Then I made the request inside useEffect, but I think this is also not a good idea, as this ties the front end with the email sending. More importantly, the request timed out in both cases (in deployment) as it took way longer for the email to get sent.

Preferably, I would like to create a system in which this email sending is handled in the background. Because whether the mail is sent or not does not affect the front end.